# Xamarin studio build target alway switches back to Retina 3.5

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to test my ios app against simulator's Retina 3.5 and 4. I need to be able to switch between them, but every time I go to the .xib file and change it from Retina 3.5 to 4, it changes back to 3.5.
There is already a bug about this issue being reopened: #16693 in bugzilla xamarin.

Is there any workaround to this. Is there a way to temporarily suspend one build target while I am working on the other?